# Usar o dockerp-lamp

Tags: docker, mint

Estou tentando user o [docker-lamp](https://github.com/jcavat/docker-lamp)

Mas toda vez que tento acessar o phpmyadmin com o login root e senha 123, dá a seguinte mensagem

```
Não é possível fazer login no servidor MySQL

 mysqli_real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

Como faço para usar o phpmyadmin, o banco caso eu queira usar a partir de um workbench?

Estou no Linux Mint 19

No docker-compose.yml deixei assim:

```
version: "3.1"
services:
    www:
        build: .
        ports: 
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - ./www:/var/www/html/
        links:
            - db
        networks:
            - default
    db:
        image: mysql:8.0
        ports: 
            - "3306:3306"
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        environment:
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: 123
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123
        volumes:
            - ./dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
            - ./conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d
            - persistent:/var/lib/mysql
        networks:
            - default
    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        links: 
            - db:db
        ports:
            - 8000:80
        environment:            
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: 123
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123
volumes:
    persistent:
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso

```
version: "3.1"
services:
    www:
        build: .
        ports: 
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - ./www:/var/www/html/
        links:
            - db

    db:
        image: mysql:8.0
        ports: 
            - "3306:3306"
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        environment:
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: 123
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123
        volumes:
            - ./dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
            - ./conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d
            - persistent:/var/lib/mysql

        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123
            MYSQL_DATABASE: bancopadrao
            MYSQL_USER: outrouser
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: outrasenha

     phpmyadmin:
            image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
            links: 
                - db:db
            ports:
                - 8000:80
            environment:
                PMA_HOST: mysql
                PMA_PORT: 3306
volumes:
    persistent:
```

Para poder acessar via workbench você deve exporá porta do banco de dados 'db' como você já está fazendo na porta 3306, só passar o banco e user e senha definidos.

Esse exemplo de um projeto meu pode te ajudar https://github.com/ggbr/lamp/blob/master/docker-compose.yml